# How to close the current window in browser after clicking ok in the alert message?

Tags: javascript, html, alert

based on some actions in a page , I want to give an alert message to the user  (ie.. your resume has been uploaded.) like that and i want to close that window, when the user clicks okay in that alert box. I want to do this using alert method only instead of confirm method in javascript. why because alert method gives the only option "ok" where as confirm method gives " yes or no" .can anyone help me please.

Comment: Script may not close the window that were not opened by script

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put the statements one after each other :

```
alert("ok");
window.close();
```

EDIT following Ankit's remark to OP : note that if you didn't open the window with Javascript yourself, you may not be authorized to close it depending on the browser.